How practical double slit experiment deviate from the young double slit experiment given in a basic physics textbook?
How practical double slit experiment differ from the young double slit experiment given in a basic physics text book? Will there be any difference in the appearance of fringes ? An elaborate comparison between real vs theoretical observations will be appreciated.

I charge US$ 400/hr.

Descriptions of the original double slit experiment performed by Young given in a basic physics text book are usually incorrect as Young used two pinholes and the resulting fringes were hyperbolae.

Have you read the Wikipedia article on Young's double-slit experiment ?
One key difference from modern versions is that Young used sunlight, which is a mix of light of different wavelengths, whereas the modern version typically uses light that is as close to a single wavelength as possible (e.g. from a laser pointer) - this makes the interference pattern sharper and thus easier to observe.
